# Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block (1 0) ERROR

Tags: boot, kernel, mount, uefi

I am trying to install UBUNTU 16.04 (amd64) alongside Windows 10 on my laptop which is UEFI boot mode.

When I boot the usb drive, it is showing this error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block (1 0)
```

My laptop model :

```
DELL 5523 Z ultrabook
UEFI bootable
```

I have already gone through `block (2 0)` and block `(0 0)` panic errors but couldn't find how to solve this problem i am facing.

Comment: How did you prepare the USB drive? It's possible that using another program (`dd`, [Rufus,](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) [UNetbootin,](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) etc.) will help. If not, you might have such new hardware that the USB port is not yet supported. There's a chance that the [16.10 pre-release](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) will work, but that's a long shot.

Comment: i used UNetbootin to prepare usb

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 boots but then it doesnt show the partition table while installating

Comment: You may have hardware that's too new for 14.04, especially if you're using something earlier than 14.04.5. I recommend you try 16.04.1, or perhaps even the current [16.10 pre-release.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/)